# In spark Data frame how to convert Date column of type string to Date column of type Date using scala

Tags: string, scala, dataframe, date, apache-spark

I have tried this way in spark

```
df.withColumn(s"$new_col_name" unix_timestamp(date_col))
```

I guess I have all the required libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured out three ways of doing it:

```
.withColumn("new_col_name", (col("date_col_oftypeString").cast("date")))
.withColumn("new_col_name",lit($"date_col_oftypeString").cast(DateType))
.withColumn("new_col_name", to_date(unix_timestamp($"date_col_oftypeString", "yyyy-MM-dd").cast("timestamp")))
```

Don't forget to import:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{DateType}

import java.sql.Timestamp

import java.util._

import spark.implicits._
```